# #!/bin/bash Problem with sed to send the attribute /n as plain txt

Tags: linux, awk, sed

i try to replace an line (variable) on an other file. On this variable i have to put /n for Newline as plain text into, because if not the programm will not use it.

**My try:**

```
sv_desc='Testing \n Another Test \n Test again'
sed -i -e 11c "server.description \"$sv_desc\"" $HOME/dirtoFile
```

**Output ist now:**

```
server.description "Another Test
Test again
Test"
```

I also tryed with "" but same output....

**I need follow output (all in one line with \n):**

```
server.description "Testing \n Another Test \n Test again"
```

Comment: Please edit: `\n` or `/n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Zachary is right. But if you do not have hands on sv_desc, you have to escape automatically. This questions helped me on a similar problem :
[Shell: Ignore escape sequences while replacing a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686766/shell-ignore-escape-sequences-while-replacing-a-pattern)

His qs function will escape \n, if comming for external source.

According to [potong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967492/potong) you could try :

```
sv_desc='Testing \n Another Test \n Test again'

qs(){ sed <<<$sv_desc 's/[][\\.*^$]/\\&/g';}

sed -i "s/^server\.description$/\"$(qs $sv_desc)\"/"  $HOME/dirtoFile
```

or

```
sed -i -e 11c "server.description \"$(qs $sv_desc)\"" $HOME/dirtoFile
```

Please see his post for more.

Answer (score 1):

Your new line characters need to be escaped with an additional back slash

```
sv_desc='Testing \\n Another Test \\n Test again'
sed -i -e 11c "server.description \"$sv_desc\"" $HOME/dirtoFile
```